# Radio buttons keep changing the selection - what's wrong?

Tags: html, google-chrome, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons and an input field. Every time I click into the input field below the radio buttons, the topmost radio button gets selected. Also when I click anywhere in what seems to be the `<label>` area, the topmost radio button gets selected. This seems to be only happening in google chrome (just tried with IE8, no problems there).

I am guessing there is something in the HTML I did wrong and I am unaware of... I am currently under the assumption that radio buttons with the same name act as one unit. But why would clicking in the text field make a difference? It has a different name...?!

```
<label class="cpr-certification marg3"> 
    <p class="color-4"><span>CPR/AED Certification</span></p>   
    <span class="nontext">
        <input type="radio" class="nontext" name="cpr_cert" value="nc">Not certified<br>    
        <input type="radio" class="nontext" name="cpr_cert" value="ip">In progress<br>  
        <input type="radio" class="nontext" name="cpr_cert" value="cc">Currently certified
    </span> 
    <input type="text" class="textinput" name="cpr_exp" placeholder="Certification expires on:">    
    <span class="error error-empty cprinfo"></span>
</label>
```

**Why does this radio button setup not work in google chrome?**

Comment: A label is only intended to wrap or target one element. You can't wrap all of them in one label.

Comment: i guess so... I changed `<label>` to `<span>` and now it seems to work!

Comment: hey, where did the answer go someone just posted? I split the label into 2 labels (one for the radios, one for the text input) and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the question comments, you only had one label for all your inputs. The following is probably more what you're after, in terms of behaviour (including selecting the correct radio button when you start typing in the text box):

```
<div class="cpr-certification marg3"> 
    <p class="color-4"><span>CPR/AED Certification</span></p>   
    <div class="nontext">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="nontext" name="cpr_cert" value="nc">
            Not certified
        </label><br>    
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="nontext" name="cpr_cert" value="ip">
            In progress
        </label><br>  
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="nontext" name="cpr_cert" value="cc">
            Currently certified
            <input type="text" class="textinput" name="cpr_exp" placeholder="Certification expires on:">
        </label>
    </div> 

    <div class="error error-empty cprinfo"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wjWvg/

Comment: oh great, from all possible solutions this one has the biggest impact on my existing code and CSS :| Guess I have to restructure a couple of things... Hey but thanks for the answer! ;-)